# SPSS descriptives long data

Tags: spss

I am trying to run descriptives (Means/frequencies) on my data that are in long format/repeated measures. So for example, for 1 participant I have:

Participant Age ID 1 25 ID 1 25 ID 1 25 ID 1 25 ID 2 (Second participant .. etc) 30

So SPSS reads that as an N of 5 and uses that to compute the mean. I want SPSS to ignore repeated cases (Only read ID 1 data as one person, ignore the other 3). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ages are always identical for all occurrences of the same ID - what you should do is aggregate (Data => aggregate) your data into a separate dataset, in which you'll take only the first age for each ID. Then you can analyse the age in the new dataset with no repetitions.

you can use this syntax:

```
DATASET DECLARE OneLinePerID.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='OneLinePerID' /BREAK=ID /age=first(age) .
dataset activate OneLinePerID.
means age.
```